# What is differential scrolling?

Tags: 2d, terminology, parallax-scrolling

I have seen the term a few times (e.g. [here](http://devmaster.net/devdb/engines/orx-portable-game-engine)). I tried looking it up but did not find much information. I thought it would be something like parallax-scrolling, but I have seen suggestions otherwise (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12645026/563765)). What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallax scrolling could be seen as a *kind* of differential scrolling.

Differential scrolling is simply an effect whereby two (or more) pieces of content scroll at different rates proportional to the *differences* in some property shared between the pieces of content. For example, as in the [demos](http://elsite.de/ds/differential_scrolling_on_multiple_columns.html) linked in your second example. The three vertical columns of text in this example scroll at different rates (based on their length), but they aren't three distinct nested scrollable areas of content. The entire page still scrolls as one unit, but the shorter columns of text move less per unit of scroll because there is less content overall for them to scroll through.

Parallax scrolling is a kind of differential scrolling trying to achieve a certain effect, specifically a parallax effect:

> /ˈparəˌlaks/ (noun) the apparent displacement of an observed object due to a change in the position of the observer

In parallax scrolling, you're moving multiple pieces of content (foreground and background layers) differently in proportion to their "distance from the viewer" property to make it appear that the background is displaced more per unit change of the "viewpoint" (even though the viewpoint may not actually be moving, you're just scrolling the background by).